# NoMethodError: Using already-defined named route in map.root call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I try the Root-URL of my Rails-App, I get the following error:

> NoMethodError undefined method `[]'
>   for :company_url:Symbol

```
# (part of the) content of my config/routes.rb
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.company 'company', :controller => 'companies', :action => 'index'
  map.root :company_url
end
```

But the API-Doc for ActionController::Routing says explicitly:

> You can also specify an
>   already-defined named route in your
>   map.root call:
>
> ```
> # In routes.rb
> map.new_session :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
> map.root :new_session
> ```

What am I doing wrong? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not mapping your named route (company) to your root, you ARE mapping and undefined route (company_url).

I *think* what you're confusing is the autogenerated URLs created by `map.resources :company` which would generate a set of *_url routes automagically. You're using map.company, a named route -- not map.resources.

Comment: Shouldn't that *_url route be there "automagically" if I see the following line after submitting 'rake routes':

company  /company  {:controller=>"companies", :action=>"index"}

?

Comment: Not in that context, no.  It'll be available in views & controllers but not as a symbol in the routes.rb nor in the models.